# How to optimize cross shard queries for scylla db using gocql

Tags: go, cql, scylla, gocql

I'm using a scylla cluster with 9 nodes and replication factor to be 3.
One application opens one connections to it, reading and writing data.

However, I notice in the scylla CQL optimization monitoring dashboard, the percentage for cross shard is very high, around 150%.

Is that normal or how can I optimize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is an issue with this metric, and it was removed in the latest dashboard
https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-monitoring/issues/659

Second, the way to reduce cross-shard messages is using Token Aware drivers, if you can. There are two Token Aware drivers at the moment: Go and Java
https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/scylla_drivers/

Comment: You should use a tokenaware and a dcaware policy https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/76e94bbd190c5e89be4d470502a27bb175c2f0f5/policies.go#L782